# OCFS2 "Heartbeat generation mismatch on device" error when mounting iscsi target

Tags: iscsi, ocfs2

As said in the title, when I want to mount a iSCSI target on one machine I get the following error:

```
(o2hb-3F92114867,7826,3):o2hb_check_own_slot:590 ERROR: Heartbeat generation mismatch on device (sdb): expected(2:0xa0cf28215b4b1ed3, 0x54d8a036), ondisk(2:0xb016e6a72676a791, 0x54d8a037)
```

The same iSCSI target is working on other machines.

Any idea what this error means?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a machine which heartbeat in the cluster although it should have been detached from it.

Weird error message, though.